# Why does async-std's task::spawn prevent subsequent lines of code from executing?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await

I'm trying to use async-std's `task::spawn`:

```
use std::time::Duration;

async fn w() {
    loop {
        task::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        println!("Tick");
    }
}

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
    println!("Start");
    task::spawn(w()).await;
    println!("End");
}
```

I expect that "End" is immediately printed after "Start", but the "Tick" loop is printed endlessly.

So what is exactly the difference to the following?

```
#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
    println!("Start");
    w().await;
    println!("End");
}
```

Comment: You’re explicitly waiting for the task to finish with `.await`, though.

Comment: So what's the difference to calling the function without task::spawn()?

Comment: *waiting **for the task to finish** with `.await`*

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what the difference it to ```w().await``` is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't `.await` the spawned task. Doing so is like joining a thread: it waits for the task to finish before continuing. The handle `spawn` returns does not need to be awaited in order for the task to be driven to completion.

```
task::spawn(w()).await;
```

As written, you are correct that `task::spawn(w()).await` is no different than `w().await`. They both block the thread waiting for `w()` to finish.

What's the purpose of awaiting a spawn call, then? It's useful if you want to spawn a background task, do some other work on the current thread, and *then* block.

```
let handle = task::spawn(w());

do_other_things_for_a_while();

// Block and retrieve the result.
let result = handle.await;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't try that. Maybe this behavior could be added to the documentation.